# Python parsing javascript

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the contents of what I am able to load from a specific webpage. The problem I am facing is extracting the data inside a dictionary. I have attempted to load the contents via JSON, but I have no luck trying to get it to work. I am trying extract the value "id", specifically what follows `"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1810494542282448836"` . I am trying to parse a specific profile on instagram, so I can grab the "id" for the profiles posts (their pictures) on their profile.

When starting a session and logging in to instagram via requests, I am executing this code to parse (To note, logging in is only necessary if the specific profile is private):

```
getProfile = session.get(PROFILE_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(getProfile.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("script", type="text/javascript")[3])
```

What I can successfully parse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":{"comment_likes":0,"comments":0,"likes":0,"relationships":0,"usertags":0},"config":{"csrf_token":"OIXAF5a6FwMQJj3vCaUQXCGUGL3sFb0Z","viewer":{"allow_contacts_sync":false,"biography":"Follow for the best social media experience. Est. 2014","external_url":null,"full_name":"Social Media Bliztexnetwork","has_profile_pic":true,"id":"6440587166","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/dd5d8db8ca1645ac8b69fdaf8886184f/5BB11538/t51.2885-19/s150x150/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/df4d5098687fe594c5b2d9750804941a/5BEC5FC8/t51.2885-19/s320x320/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg","username":"bliztezxxmedia"}},"supports_es6":false,"country_code":"US","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":[{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_7507466602","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"What a wonderful day!!!","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":null,"external_url_linkshimmed":null,"edge_followed_by":{"count":17},"followed_by_viewer":true,"edge_follow":{"count":8},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Verna Manning","has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":0,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"7507466602","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"mutual_followers":{"additional_count":-3,"usernames":[]},"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg","requested_by_viewer":false,"username":"vernamanning46464","connected_fb_page":null,"edge_felix_combined_post_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_combined_draft_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_video_timeline":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_drafts":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_pending_post_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_pending_draft_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":2,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":"AQAQt_06KHhticevO8Am12l3GJ1CdrZVdUztIDyZN7oXm_IVmr2Clwi844aWh9oe9TU"},"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1810494542282448836","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"What a sunny day!"}}]},"shortcode":"BkgKzGch1_EsxkqWK-4ZjG_XoWfrFxgXIOrZqs0","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":24},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1530047789,"dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d82d797684ce57fef7a9fe87c74d2342/5BCE0CF2/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","edge_liked_by":{"count":0},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":0},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqnuL0Qj5cMT0Gf1rBdi5LHqasXLK8hZBtB7fz/WoMV1xjZGLZHijFSbaNtXYVwhgaZtq/n2H1q9/Zn/TRfyNVAxUYHGetNyfU1LT6DuXnsnTn09f6VX21tERy/wAZCjt3P41BNaqMGLkHj1pRl0luJrqjM20m2rrwGM7TjPtzTobYynGQB3J7VpdWv0I8ihtpNtdGkdvGnlvtb1PqaZstPQfmf8az9ouzL5X3RmLMGPIxgdulSiYDgZAPNVQOB/nvSjmvP9pLa5fKibzlPTmjzlH0qMKB27H+ZqOn7SXcXKiwZFAzTPNHpVVSc1ISaPaz7i5Uf//Z","owner":{"id":"7507466602"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b499ce5fafa113fe57f7325d86628900/5BE96296/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f124ca8254e24569515be5f3f99ff911/5BE9A3A9/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5c82e7c2ae3905863fe25150fca1f5e4/5BCB4ED1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e76685c6614c444d8ed5f04efc01435a/5BB6D257/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1757529388200541080","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"What a nice day."}}]},"shortcode":"Bhj_6qyALuYgmy2sPgmUtoBcmcxZWGeyLkM3O00","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":3},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1523733851,"dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/16610d58bb6cc90893ffd264f81755c6/5BAD1DBC/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","edge_liked_by":{"count":1},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":1},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqwgadupijNLn0oAdvNPErDoahopiLkdw6nIPNTfaX9apxDNS7fencLDIAP1qFsZ4qYAx9CDmmMmD1B/GsxkRoqXbnjjP1FN2H2/MVVwHKcVJvqLYf8ml2tSAtbce/vjFIFYeh/Sn0Uhjh7gU8Njjt+dMFLQA4Y9B+HFO+X0/z+VMpaAP/2Q==","owner":{"id":"7507466602"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d69525a20a2e61b2ee8663daf287a8ee/5BB46AD8/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/4034b1752e3a4bace405aadd5a35477c/5BCB79E7/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96b684f38cb826f3efd8a7610ed6e9bb/5BEB899F/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/51dac35520bc90d7c7253cc331acf561/5BB44919/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false}}]},"edge_saved_media":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_media_collections":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}}},"felix_onboarding_video_resources":{"mp4":"/static/videos/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideo.mp4/9d16838ca7f9.mp4","poster":"/static/images/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideoPoster.png/8fdba7cf2120.png"}}]},"gatekeepers":{"ld":true,"rt":true,"sw":true,"vl":true,"seo":true,"seoht":true,"2fac":true,"sf":true,"saa":true,"ai":true},"knobs":{"acct:ntb":0,"cb":0,"captcha":0},"qe":{"dash_for_vod":{"g":"","p":{}},"aysf":{"g":"","p":{}},"bc3l":{"g":"","p":{}},"comment_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"direct_conversation_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"direct_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"media_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"acc_recovery_link":{"g":"","p":{}},"notif":{"g":"","p":{}},"drct_nav":{"g":"","p":{}},"fb_unlink":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_stories_doodling":{"g":"","p":{}},"move_comment_input_to_top":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_cancel":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_search_redesign":{"g":"","p":{}},"show_copy_link":{"g":"control","p":{"show_copy_link_option":"false"}},"mobile_logout":{"g":"","p":{}},"pl_pivot_li":{"g":"control_0423","p":{"show_pivot":"false"}},"pl_pivot_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"404_as_react":{"g":"","p":{}},"acc_recovery":{"g":"test_with_prefill","p":{"has_prefill":"true"}},"collections":{"g":"","p":{}},"comment_ta":{"g":"","p":{}},"connections":{"g":"control","p":{"has_suggestion_context_in_feed":"false"}},"disc_ppl":{"g":"control_02_27","p":{"has_follow_all_button":"false","has_pagination":"false"}},"embeds":{"g":"","p":{}},"ebdsim_li":{"g":"control_shadow_0322","p":{"is_shadow_enabled":"false","use_new_ui":"true"}},"ebdsim_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"empty_feed":{"g":"","p":{}},"bundles":{"g":"","p":{}},"exit_story_creation":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_logged_out":{"g":"","p":{}},"appsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"imgopt":{"g":"control","p":{}},"follow_button":{"g":"test","p":{"is_inline":"true"}},"loggedout":{"g":"","p":{}},"loggedout_upsell":{"g":"test_with_new_loggedout_upsell_content_03_15_18","p":{"has_new_loggedout_upsell_content":"true"}},"us_li":{"g":"Test","p":{"show_related_media":"true"}},"msisdn":{"g":"","p":{}},"bg_sync":{"g":"","p":{}},"onetaplogin":{"g":"default_opt_in","p":{"default_value":"true","during_reg":"true","storage_version":"one_tap_storage_version"}},"onetaplogin_userbased":{"g":"","p":{}},"login_poe":{"g":"","p":{}},"prvcy_tggl":{"g":"","p":{}},"private_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"profile_photo_nux_fbc_v2":{"g":"launch","p":{"prefill_photo":"true","skip_nux":"false"}},"profile_tabs":{"g":"","p":{}},"push_notifications":{"g":"","p":{}},"reg":{"g":"control_01_10","p":{"has_new_landing_appsells":"false","has_new_landing_page":"false"}},"reg_vp":{"g":"","p":{}},"feed_vp":{"g":"launch","p":{"is_hidden":"true"}},"report_haf":{"g":"","p":{}},"report_media":{"g":"","p":{}},"report_profile":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"save":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"sidecar":{"g":"","p":{}},"sidecar_swipe":{"g":"","p":{}},"su_universe":{"g":"test_login_autocomplete","p":{"use_autocomplete_signup":"true"}},"stale":{"g":"","p":{}},"stories_lo":{"g":"test_03_15","p":{"stories_profile":"true"}},"stories":{"g":"","p":{}},"tp_pblshr":{"g":"","p":{}},"video":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_settings":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_blocking_logout":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_eu_tos":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_row_tos":{"g":"test_05_01","p":{"tos_version":"row"}},"fd_gr":{"g":"control","p":{"show_post_back_button":"false"}},"felix":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_clear_fb_cookie":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"true","blacklist":"fbsr_124024574287414"}},"felix_creation_duration_limits":{"g":"dogfooding","p":{"minimum_length_seconds":"15","maximum_length_seconds":"600"}},"felix_creation_enabled":{"g":"","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"false"}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_creation_validation":{"g":"control","p":{"edit_video_controls":"true"}},"felix_creation_video_upload":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_early_onboarding":{"g":"","p":{}},"pride":{"g":"test","p":{"enabled":"true","hashtag_whitelist":"lgbt,lesbian,gay,bisexual,transgender,trans,queer,lgbtq,girlslikeus,girlswholikegirls,instagay,pride,gaypride,loveislove,pansexual,lovewins,transequalitynow,lesbiansofinstagram,asexual,nonbinary,lgbtpride,lgbta,lgbti,queerfashion,queers,queerpride,queerlife,marriageequality,pride2018,genderqueer,bi,genderfluid,lgbtqqia,comingout,intersex,transman,transwoman,twospirit,transvisibility,queerart,dragqueen,dragking,dragartist,twomoms,twodads,lesbianmoms,gaydads,gendernonconforming"}},"unfollow_confirm":{"g":"","p":{}},"profile_enhance_li":{"g":"control","p":{"has_tagged":"false"}},"profile_enhance_lo":{"g":"control","p":{"has_tagged":"false"}},"create_tag":{"g":"","p":{}}},"hostname":"www.instagram.com","platform":"ios","rhx_gis":"87a25368813608d393baaa28a0d6afb7","nonce":"zsP4NjzdJRIWmer6K5At1A==","zero_data":{},"rollout_hash":"5f72737283f8","bundle_variant":"base","probably_has_app":false,"show_app_install":true}
```

Thanks to all of those in advance who reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import json
import re
s = """<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"activity_counts":{"comment_likes":0,"comments":0,"likes":0,"relationships":0,"usertags":0},"config":{"csrf_token":"OIXAF5a6FwMQJj3vCaUQXCGUGL3sFb0Z","viewer":{"allow_contacts_sync":false,"biography":"Follow for the best social media experience. Est. 2014","external_url":null,"full_name":"Social Media Bliztexnetwork","has_profile_pic":true,"id":"6440587166","profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/dd5d8db8ca1645ac8b69fdaf8886184f/5BB11538/t51.2885-19/s150x150/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/df4d5098687fe594c5b2d9750804941a/5BEC5FC8/t51.2885-19/s320x320/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg","username":"bliztezxxmedia"}},"supports_es6":false,"country_code":"US","language_code":"en","locale":"en_US","entry_data":{"ProfilePage":[{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_7507466602","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"What a wonderful day!!!","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":null,"external_url_linkshimmed":null,"edge_followed_by":{"count":17},"followed_by_viewer":true,"edge_follow":{"count":8},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"Verna Manning","has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":0,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"7507466602","is_private":true,"is_verified":false,"mutual_followers":{"additional_count":-3,"usernames":[]},"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg","profile_pic_url_hd":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg","requested_by_viewer":false,"username":"vernamanning46464","connected_fb_page":null,"edge_felix_combined_post_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_combined_draft_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_video_timeline":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_drafts":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_pending_post_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_felix_pending_draft_uploads":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":2,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":"AQAQt_06KHhticevO8Am12l3GJ1CdrZVdUztIDyZN7oXm_IVmr2Clwi844aWh9oe9TU"},"edges":[{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1810494542282448836","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"What a sunny day!"}}]},"shortcode":"BkgKzGch1_EsxkqWK-4ZjG_XoWfrFxgXIOrZqs0","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":24},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1530047789,"dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d82d797684ce57fef7a9fe87c74d2342/5BCE0CF2/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","edge_liked_by":{"count":0},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":0},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqnuL0Qj5cMT0Gf1rBdi5LHqasXLK8hZBtB7fz/WoMV1xjZGLZHijFSbaNtXYVwhgaZtq/n2H1q9/Zn/TRfyNVAxUYHGetNyfU1LT6DuXnsnTn09f6VX21tERy/wAZCjt3P41BNaqMGLkHj1pRl0luJrqjM20m2rrwGM7TjPtzTobYynGQB3J7VpdWv0I8ihtpNtdGkdvGnlvtb1PqaZstPQfmf8az9ouzL5X3RmLMGPIxgdulSiYDgZAPNVQOB/nvSjmvP9pLa5fKibzlPTmjzlH0qMKB27H+ZqOn7SXcXKiwZFAzTPNHpVVSc1ISaPaz7i5Uf//Z","owner":{"id":"7507466602"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b499ce5fafa113fe57f7325d86628900/5BE96296/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f124ca8254e24569515be5f3f99ff911/5BE9A3A9/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5c82e7c2ae3905863fe25150fca1f5e4/5BCB4ED1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e76685c6614c444d8ed5f04efc01435a/5BB6D257/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false}},{"node":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1757529388200541080","edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[{"node":{"text":"What a nice day."}}]},"shortcode":"Bhj_6qyALuYgmy2sPgmUtoBcmcxZWGeyLkM3O00","edge_media_to_comment":{"count":3},"comments_disabled":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1523733851,"dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"display_url":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/16610d58bb6cc90893ffd264f81755c6/5BAD1DBC/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","edge_liked_by":{"count":1},"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":1},"gating_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqwgadupijNLn0oAdvNPErDoahopiLkdw6nIPNTfaX9apxDNS7fencLDIAP1qFsZ4qYAx9CDmmMmD1B/GsxkRoqXbnjjP1FN2H2/MVVwHKcVJvqLYf8ml2tSAtbce/vjFIFYeh/Sn0Uhjh7gU8Njjt+dMFLQA4Y9B+HFO+X0/z+VMpaAP/2Q==","owner":{"id":"7507466602"},"thumbnail_src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","thumbnail_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d69525a20a2e61b2ee8663daf287a8ee/5BB46AD8/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":150,"config_height":150},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/4034b1752e3a4bace405aadd5a35477c/5BCB79E7/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":240,"config_height":240},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96b684f38cb826f3efd8a7610ed6e9bb/5BEB899F/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":320,"config_height":320},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/51dac35520bc90d7c7253cc331acf561/5BB44919/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":480,"config_height":480},{"src":"https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg","config_width":640,"config_height":640}],"is_video":false}}]},"edge_saved_media":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_media_collections":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]}}},"felix_onboarding_video_resources":{"mp4":"/static/videos/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideo.mp4/9d16838ca7f9.mp4","poster":"/static/images/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideoPoster.png/8fdba7cf2120.png"}}]},"gatekeepers":{"ld":true,"rt":true,"sw":true,"vl":true,"seo":true,"seoht":true,"2fac":true,"sf":true,"saa":true,"ai":true},"knobs":{"acct:ntb":0,"cb":0,"captcha":0},"qe":{"dash_for_vod":{"g":"","p":{}},"aysf":{"g":"","p":{}},"bc3l":{"g":"","p":{}},"comment_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"direct_conversation_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"direct_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"media_reporting":{"g":"","p":{}},"acc_recovery_link":{"g":"","p":{}},"notif":{"g":"","p":{}},"drct_nav":{"g":"","p":{}},"fb_unlink":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_stories_doodling":{"g":"","p":{}},"move_comment_input_to_top":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_cancel":{"g":"","p":{}},"mobile_search_redesign":{"g":"","p":{}},"show_copy_link":{"g":"control","p":{"show_copy_link_option":"false"}},"mobile_logout":{"g":"","p":{}},"pl_pivot_li":{"g":"control_0423","p":{"show_pivot":"false"}},"pl_pivot_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"404_as_react":{"g":"","p":{}},"acc_recovery":{"g":"test_with_prefill","p":{"has_prefill":"true"}},"collections":{"g":"","p":{}},"comment_ta":{"g":"","p":{}},"connections":{"g":"control","p":{"has_suggestion_context_in_feed":"false"}},"disc_ppl":{"g":"control_02_27","p":{"has_follow_all_button":"false","has_pagination":"false"}},"embeds":{"g":"","p":{}},"ebdsim_li":{"g":"control_shadow_0322","p":{"is_shadow_enabled":"false","use_new_ui":"true"}},"ebdsim_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"empty_feed":{"g":"","p":{}},"bundles":{"g":"","p":{}},"exit_story_creation":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_logged_out":{"g":"","p":{}},"appsell":{"g":"","p":{}},"imgopt":{"g":"control","p":{}},"follow_button":{"g":"test","p":{"is_inline":"true"}},"loggedout":{"g":"","p":{}},"loggedout_upsell":{"g":"test_with_new_loggedout_upsell_content_03_15_18","p":{"has_new_loggedout_upsell_content":"true"}},"us_li":{"g":"Test","p":{"show_related_media":"true"}},"msisdn":{"g":"","p":{}},"bg_sync":{"g":"","p":{}},"onetaplogin":{"g":"default_opt_in","p":{"default_value":"true","during_reg":"true","storage_version":"one_tap_storage_version"}},"onetaplogin_userbased":{"g":"","p":{}},"login_poe":{"g":"","p":{}},"prvcy_tggl":{"g":"","p":{}},"private_lo":{"g":"","p":{}},"profile_photo_nux_fbc_v2":{"g":"launch","p":{"prefill_photo":"true","skip_nux":"false"}},"profile_tabs":{"g":"","p":{}},"push_notifications":{"g":"","p":{}},"reg":{"g":"control_01_10","p":{"has_new_landing_appsells":"false","has_new_landing_page":"false"}},"reg_vp":{"g":"","p":{}},"feed_vp":{"g":"launch","p":{"is_hidden":"true"}},"report_haf":{"g":"","p":{}},"report_media":{"g":"","p":{}},"report_profile":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"save":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"sidecar":{"g":"","p":{}},"sidecar_swipe":{"g":"","p":{}},"su_universe":{"g":"test_login_autocomplete","p":{"use_autocomplete_signup":"true"}},"stale":{"g":"","p":{}},"stories_lo":{"g":"test_03_15","p":{"stories_profile":"true"}},"stories":{"g":"","p":{}},"tp_pblshr":{"g":"","p":{}},"video":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_settings":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_blocking_logout":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_eu_tos":{"g":"","p":{}},"gdpr_row_tos":{"g":"test_05_01","p":{"tos_version":"row"}},"fd_gr":{"g":"control","p":{"show_post_back_button":"false"}},"felix":{"g":"test","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_clear_fb_cookie":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"true","blacklist":"fbsr_124024574287414"}},"felix_creation_duration_limits":{"g":"dogfooding","p":{"minimum_length_seconds":"15","maximum_length_seconds":"600"}},"felix_creation_enabled":{"g":"","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"false"}},"felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2":{"g":"control","p":{"is_enabled":"true"}},"felix_creation_validation":{"g":"control","p":{"edit_video_controls":"true"}},"felix_creation_video_upload":{"g":"","p":{}},"felix_early_onboarding":{"g":"","p":{}},"pride":{"g":"test","p":{"enabled":"true","hashtag_whitelist":"lgbt,lesbian,gay,bisexual,transgender,trans,queer,lgbtq,girlslikeus,girlswholikegirls,instagay,pride,gaypride,loveislove,pansexual,lovewins,transequalitynow,lesbiansofinstagram,asexual,nonbinary,lgbtpride,lgbta,lgbti,queerfashion,queers,queerpride,queerlife,marriageequality,pride2018,genderqueer,bi,genderfluid,lgbtqqia,comingout,intersex,transman,transwoman,twospirit,transvisibility,queerart,dragqueen,dragking,dragartist,twomoms,twodads,lesbianmoms,gaydads,gendernonconforming"}},"unfollow_confirm":{"g":"","p":{}},"profile_enhance_li":{"g":"control","p":{"has_tagged":"false"}},"profile_enhance_lo":{"g":"control","p":{"has_tagged":"false"}},"create_tag":{"g":"","p":{}}},"hostname":"www.instagram.com","platform":"ios","rhx_gis":"87a25368813608d393baaa28a0d6afb7","nonce":"zsP4NjzdJRIWmer6K5At1A==","zero_data":{},"rollout_hash":"5f72737283f8","bundle_variant":"base","probably_has_app":false,"show_app_install":true}</script>"""
m = re.search(r"(?<=window._sharedData = )(?P<json>.*)(?=</script>)", s)
if m:
    data = json.loads(m.group('json'))
    print(data)
    for i in data['entry_data']["ProfilePage"]:
        for j in i['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
            print(j['node']["id"])
```

**Output:**

```
{u'nonce': u'zsP4NjzdJRIWmer6K5At1A==', u'probably_has_app': False, u'show_app_install': True, u'platform': u'ios', u'locale': u'en_US', u'activity_counts': {u'relationships': 0, u'usertags': 0, u'comment_likes': 0, u'likes': 0, u'comments': 0}, u'hostname': u'www.instagram.com', u'rollout_hash': u'5f72737283f8', u'bundle_variant': u'base', u'entry_data': {u'ProfilePage': [{u'felix_onboarding_video_resources': {u'poster': u'/static/images/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideoPoster.png/8fdba7cf2120.png', u'mp4': u'/static/videos/felix-onboarding/onboardingVideo.mp4/9d16838ca7f9.mp4'}, u'logging_page_id': u'profilePage_7507466602', u'show_suggested_profiles': False, u'graphql': {u'user': {u'external_url_linkshimmed': None, u'has_requested_viewer': False, u'highlight_reel_count': 0, u'edge_felix_combined_post_uploads': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'full_name': u'Verna Manning', u'blocked_by_viewer': False, u'id': u'7507466602', u'biography': u'What a wonderful day!!!', u'edge_follow': {u'count': 8}, u'edge_felix_drafts': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'edge_felix_combined_draft_uploads': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'followed_by_viewer': True, u'follows_viewer': False, u'edge_saved_media': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'edge_media_collections': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'is_verified': False, u'username': u'vernamanning46464', u'edge_owner_to_timeline_media': {u'count': 2, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': u'AQAQt_06KHhticevO8Am12l3GJ1CdrZVdUztIDyZN7oXm_IVmr2Clwi844aWh9oe9TU', u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': [{u'node': {u'edge_media_preview_like': {u'count': 0}, u'is_video': False, u'edge_media_to_caption': {u'edges': [{u'node': {u'text': u'What a sunny day!'}}]}, u'dimensions': {u'width': 1080, u'height': 1080}, u'display_url': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d82d797684ce57fef7a9fe87c74d2342/5BCE0CF2/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'edge_media_to_comment': {u'count': 24}, u'comments_disabled': False, u'__typename': u'GraphImage', u'owner': {u'id': u'7507466602'}, u'media_preview': u'ACoqnuL0Qj5cMT0Gf1rBdi5LHqasXLK8hZBtB7fz/WoMV1xjZGLZHijFSbaNtXYVwhgaZtq/n2H1q9/Zn/TRfyNVAxUYHGetNyfU1LT6DuXnsnTn09f6VX21tERy/wAZCjt3P41BNaqMGLkHj1pRl0luJrqjM20m2rrwGM7TjPtzTobYynGQB3J7VpdWv0I8ihtpNtdGkdvGnlvtb1PqaZstPQfmf8az9ouzL5X3RmLMGPIxgdulSiYDgZAPNVQOB/nvSjmvP9pLa5fKibzlPTmjzlH0qMKB27H+ZqOn7SXcXKiwZFAzTPNHpVVSc1ISaPaz7i5Uf//Z', u'edge_liked_by': {u'count': 0}, u'thumbnail_resources': [{u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/b499ce5fafa113fe57f7325d86628900/5BE96296/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'config_width': 150, u'config_height': 150}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/f124ca8254e24569515be5f3f99ff911/5BE9A3A9/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'config_width': 240, u'config_height': 240}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/5c82e7c2ae3905863fe25150fca1f5e4/5BCB4ED1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'config_width': 320, u'config_height': 320}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e76685c6614c444d8ed5f04efc01435a/5BB6D257/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'config_width': 480, u'config_height': 480}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'config_width': 640, u'config_height': 640}], u'taken_at_timestamp': 1530047789, u'gating_info': None, u'thumbnail_src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/7cecb59edaba9f9f7565604eac28d8df/5BC63210/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/35274418_207295373248007_2552664476088270848_n.jpg', u'shortcode': u'BkgKzGch1_EsxkqWK-4ZjG_XoWfrFxgXIOrZqs0', u'id': u'1810494542282448836'}}, {u'node': {u'edge_media_preview_like': {u'count': 1}, u'is_video': False, u'edge_media_to_caption': {u'edges': [{u'node': {u'text': u'What a nice day.'}}]}, u'dimensions': {u'width': 1080, u'height': 1080}, u'display_url': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/16610d58bb6cc90893ffd264f81755c6/5BAD1DBC/t51.2885-15/s1080x1080/e15/fr/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'edge_media_to_comment': {u'count': 3}, u'comments_disabled': False, u'__typename': u'GraphImage', u'owner': {u'id': u'7507466602'}, u'media_preview': u'ACoqwgadupijNLn0oAdvNPErDoahopiLkdw6nIPNTfaX9apxDNS7fencLDIAP1qFsZ4qYAx9CDmmMmD1B/GsxkRoqXbnjjP1FN2H2/MVVwHKcVJvqLYf8ml2tSAtbce/vjFIFYeh/Sn0Uhjh7gU8Njjt+dMFLQA4Y9B+HFO+X0/z+VMpaAP/2Q==', u'edge_liked_by': {u'count': 1}, u'thumbnail_resources': [{u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/d69525a20a2e61b2ee8663daf287a8ee/5BB46AD8/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'config_width': 150, u'config_height': 150}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/4034b1752e3a4bace405aadd5a35477c/5BCB79E7/t51.2885-15/s240x240/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'config_width': 240, u'config_height': 240}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96b684f38cb826f3efd8a7610ed6e9bb/5BEB899F/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'config_width': 320, u'config_height': 320}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/51dac35520bc90d7c7253cc331acf561/5BB44919/t51.2885-15/s480x480/e15/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'config_width': 480, u'config_height': 480}, {u'src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'config_width': 640, u'config_height': 640}], u'taken_at_timestamp': 1523733851, u'gating_info': None, u'thumbnail_src': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/a4dfd1c28505301d4c440c95023fbbc7/5BC81D5E/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/30590929_101347367387069_7153309976138612736_n.jpg', u'shortcode': u'Bhj_6qyALuYgmy2sPgmUtoBcmcxZWGeyLkM3O00', u'id': u'1757529388200541080'}}]}, u'country_block': False, u'edge_followed_by': {u'count': 17}, u'edge_felix_pending_draft_uploads': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'mutual_followers': {u'usernames': [], u'additional_count': -3}, u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg', u'has_channel': False, u'is_private': True, u'connected_fb_page': None, u'edge_felix_pending_post_uploads': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'requested_by_viewer': False, u'profile_pic_url_hd': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/96e65311d0a5e79729411bd582592816/5BCC9C5A/t51.2885-19/s150x150/33143922_237271910362316_6290555001760645120_n.jpg', u'has_blocked_viewer': False, u'edge_felix_video_timeline': {u'count': 0, u'page_info': {u'end_cursor': None, u'has_next_page': False}, u'edges': []}, u'external_url': None}}}]}, u'zero_data': {}, u'rhx_gis': u'87a25368813608d393baaa28a0d6afb7', u'qe': {u'gdpr_blocking_logout': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'reg': {u'p': {u'has_new_landing_page': u'false', u'has_new_landing_appsells': u'false'}, u'g': u'control_01_10'}, u'gdpr_eu_tos': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'gdpr_settings': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'mobile_search_redesign': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'bundles': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'pl_pivot_li': {u'p': {u'show_pivot': u'false'}, u'g': u'control_0423'}, u'felix': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true'}, u'g': u'test'}, u'pl_pivot_lo': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'direct_conversation_reporting': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'report_profile': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true'}, u'g': u'test'}, u'unfollow_confirm': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'connections': {u'p': {u'has_suggestion_context_in_feed': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'video': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'aysf': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'exit_story_creation': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'profile_photo_nux_fbc_v2': {u'p': {u'prefill_photo': u'true', u'skip_nux': u'false'}, u'g': u'launch'}, u'feed_vp': {u'p': {u'is_hidden': u'true'}, u'g': u'launch'}, u'sidecar': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'felix_clear_fb_cookie': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true', u'blacklist': u'fbsr_124024574287414'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'felix_creation_fb_crossposting': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'save': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true'}, u'g': u'test'}, u'stories_lo': {u'p': {u'stories_profile': u'true'}, u'g': u'test_03_15'}, u'felix_creation_fb_crossposting_v2': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'report_media': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'mobile_logout': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'fb_unlink': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'gdpr_row_tos': {u'p': {u'tos_version': u'row'}, u'g': u'test_05_01'}, u'create_tag': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'media_reporting': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'felix_creation_validation': {u'p': {u'edit_video_controls': u'true'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'pride': {u'p': {u'enabled': u'true', u'hashtag_whitelist': u'lgbt,lesbian,gay,bisexual,transgender,trans,queer,lgbtq,girlslikeus,girlswholikegirls,instagay,pride,gaypride,loveislove,pansexual,lovewins,transequalitynow,lesbiansofinstagram,asexual,nonbinary,lgbtpride,lgbta,lgbti,queerfashion,queers,queerpride,queerlife,marriageequality,pride2018,genderqueer,bi,genderfluid,lgbtqqia,comingout,intersex,transman,transwoman,twospirit,transvisibility,queerart,dragqueen,dragking,dragartist,twomoms,twodads,lesbianmoms,gaydads,gendernonconforming'}, u'g': u'test'}, u'msisdn': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'collections': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'drct_nav': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'onetaplogin_userbased': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'bg_sync': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'acc_recovery_link': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'empty_feed': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'ebdsim_lo': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'gdpr_logged_out': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'follow_button': {u'p': {u'is_inline': u'true'}, u'g': u'test'}, u'profile_tabs': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'reporting': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'private_lo': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'404_as_react': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'embeds': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'push_notifications': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'notif': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'tp_pblshr': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'felix_creation_enabled': {u'p': {u'is_enabled': u'true'}, u'g': u''}, u'report_haf': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'acc_recovery': {u'p': {u'has_prefill': u'true'}, u'g': u'test_with_prefill'}, u'comment_reporting': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'felix_early_onboarding': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'felix_creation_video_upload': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'appsell': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'us_li': {u'p': {u'show_related_media': u'true'}, u'g': u'Test'}, u'bc3l': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'stale': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'dash_for_vod': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'su_universe': {u'p': {u'use_autocomplete_signup': u'true'}, u'g': u'test_login_autocomplete'}, u'profile_enhance_li': {u'p': {u'has_tagged': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'move_comment_input_to_top': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'imgopt': {u'p': {}, u'g': u'control'}, u'ebdsim_li': {u'p': {u'is_shadow_enabled': u'false', u'use_new_ui': u'true'}, u'g': u'control_shadow_0322'}, u'loggedout_upsell': {u'p': {u'has_new_loggedout_upsell_content': u'true'}, u'g': u'test_with_new_loggedout_upsell_content_03_15_18'}, u'felix_creation_duration_limits': {u'p': {u'minimum_length_seconds': u'15', u'maximum_length_seconds': u'600'}, u'g': u'dogfooding'}, u'sidecar_swipe': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'direct_reporting': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'mobile_stories_doodling': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'login_poe': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'profile_enhance_lo': {u'p': {u'has_tagged': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'show_copy_link': {u'p': {u'show_copy_link_option': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'loggedout': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'onetaplogin': {u'p': {u'default_value': u'true', u'storage_version': u'one_tap_storage_version', u'during_reg': u'true'}, u'g': u'default_opt_in'}, u'fd_gr': {u'p': {u'show_post_back_button': u'false'}, u'g': u'control'}, u'stories': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'disc_ppl': {u'p': {u'has_follow_all_button': u'false', u'has_pagination': u'false'}, u'g': u'control_02_27'}, u'prvcy_tggl': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'reg_vp': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'mobile_cancel': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}, u'comment_ta': {u'p': {}, u'g': u''}}, u'country_code': u'US', u'language_code': u'en', u'gatekeepers': {u'rt': True, u'ld': True, u'ai': True, u'sw': True, u'saa': True, u'vl': True, u'2fac': True, u'seo': True, u'seoht': True, u'sf': True}, u'knobs': {u'captcha': 0, u'cb': 0, u'acct:ntb': 0}, u'config': {u'viewer': {u'username': u'bliztezxxmedia', u'allow_contacts_sync': False, u'has_profile_pic': True, u'profile_pic_url_hd': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/df4d5098687fe594c5b2d9750804941a/5BEC5FC8/t51.2885-19/s320x320/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg', u'profile_pic_url': u'https://instagram.fbed1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/dd5d8db8ca1645ac8b69fdaf8886184f/5BB11538/t51.2885-19/s150x150/32947488_229940584435561_2806247690365566976_n.jpg', u'full_name': u'Social Media Bliztexnetwork', u'id': u'6440587166', u'biography': u'Follow for the best social media experience. Est. 2014', u'external_url': None}, u'csrf_token': u'OIXAF5a6FwMQJj3vCaUQXCGUGL3sFb0Z'}, u'supports_es6': False}

1810494542282448836
1757529388200541080
```

Comment: So, I am storing the parsing done by beautiful soup into s now, (which is the soup.find_all("script", type="text/javascript")[3]) , and I am receiving an error, stating: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 12149 (char 12148)

Comment: You are getting the error because you missed `</script>` at the end of your sample data..updated snippet.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, and I am not to sure why. The error has changed slightly though: Extra data: line 1 column 12280 (char 12279) I am thinking it has to do with the "?<=window._sharedData" Should that be changed to something with "<script type="text/javascript">" instead?

Comment: Still seeking help with this question. Thanks to all who have contributed thus far.